# How do I represent an entity being composed of 3 other entities?

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I want to represent in my ER diagram that a pack is composed of three (3) different games.

[My current ER model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olCh8.png)

As you can see in the above image, both the packs and the games are a product with their respective attributes.

This is their respective tables:

```
packs(id, game1_id, game2_id, game3_id) where id is the primary key (also a foreign key of products)

games(id, studio_id) where id is the primary key (also a foreign key of products)
```

I can't seem to find any examples on how to show what I mean in the model, so if anyone knows I would appreciate it.

Comment: three (3) different games exactly? Can this number vary over packs?

Comment: Yes yes, three different games, always

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CHECK constraint to ensure all 3 games are different.

```
create table packs(
  id       int not null primary key, 
  game1_id int not null, 
  game2_id int not null, 
  game3_id int not null,
  constraint c12 check (game1_id <> game2_id), 
  constraint c23 check (game2_id <> game3_id), 
  constraint c31 check (game3_id <> game1_id),
  -- FKs 
  constraint fk1 foreign key (game1_id) references games(id),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (game2_id) references games(id),
  constraint fk3 foreign key (game3_id) references games(id)
)
```

Comment: I was asking regarding the model represantation, like the image I attached